# Training the BERT model with pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, pytorch-lightning

I am unable to figure out why my BERT model dosen't get pas the training command. I am using pytorch-lightning. I am running the code on AWS EC2(p3.2xLarge) and it does show me the available GPU but I can't really figure out the device side error. Could someone please guide me towards a direction? I really appreciate you time and consideration.
PS: The results are after setting CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.

```
trainer = pl.Trainer(
  logger=logger,
  checkpoint_callback=checkpoint_callback,
  callbacks=[early_stopping_callback],
  max_epochs=N_EPOCHS,
  gpus=1,
  progress_bar_refresh_rate=30,
)
GPU available: True, used: True
TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
In [155]:

trainer.fit(model, data_module)
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-155-7b6b8391c42e> in <module>
----> 1 trainer.fit(model, data_module)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in fit(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, train_dataloader, ckpt_path)
    739             train_dataloaders = train_dataloader
    740         self._call_and_handle_interrupt(
--> 741             self._fit_impl, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path
    742         )
    743 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _call_and_handle_interrupt(self, trainer_fn, *args, **kwargs)
    683         """
    684         try:
--> 685             return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    686         # TODO: treat KeyboardInterrupt as BaseException (delete the code below) in v1.7
    687         except KeyboardInterrupt as exception:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _fit_impl(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path)
    775         # TODO: ckpt_path only in v1.7
    776         ckpt_path = ckpt_path or self.resume_from_checkpoint
--> 777         self._run(model, ckpt_path=ckpt_path)
    778 
    779         assert self.state.stopped

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _run(self, model, ckpt_path)
   1143 
   1144         self._call_configure_sharded_model()  # allow user to setup in model sharded environment
-> 1145         self.accelerator.setup(self)
   1146 
   1147         # ----------------------------

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/gpu.py in setup(self, trainer)
     44     def setup(self, trainer: "pl.Trainer") -> None:
     45         self.set_nvidia_flags(trainer.local_rank)
---> 46         return super().setup(trainer)
     47 
     48     def on_train_start(self) -> None:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py in setup(self, trainer)
     89             trainer: the trainer instance
     90         """
---> 91         self.setup_training_type_plugin()
     92         if not self.training_type_plugin.setup_optimizers_in_pre_dispatch:
     93             self.setup_optimizers(trainer)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py in setup_training_type_plugin(self)
    361     def setup_training_type_plugin(self) -> None:
    362         """Attaches the training type plugin to the accelerator."""
--> 363         self.training_type_plugin.setup()
    364 
    365     def setup_precision_plugin(self) -> None:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/training_type/single_device.py in setup(self)
     69 
     70     def setup(self) -> None:
---> 71         self.model_to_device()
     72 
     73     @property

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/training_type/single_device.py in model_to_device(self)
     66 
     67     def model_to_device(self) -> None:
---> 68         self._model.to(self.root_device)
     69 
     70     def setup(self) -> None:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/mixins/device_dtype_mixin.py in to(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109         out = torch._C._nn._parse_to(*args, **kwargs)
    110         self.__update_properties(device=out[0], dtype=out[1])
--> 111         return super().to(*args, **kwargs)
    112 
    113     def cuda(self, device: Optional[Union[torch.device, int]] = None) -> "DeviceDtypeModuleMixin":

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in to(self, *args, **kwargs)
    897             return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)
    898 
--> 899         return self._apply(convert)
    900 
    901     def register_backward_hook(

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _apply(self, fn)
    568     def _apply(self, fn):
    569         for module in self.children():
--> 570             module._apply(fn)
    571 
    572         def compute_should_use_set_data(tensor, tensor_applied):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _apply(self, fn)
    568     def _apply(self, fn):
    569         for module in self.children():
--> 570             module._apply(fn)
    571 
    572         def compute_should_use_set_data(tensor, tensor_applied):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _apply(self, fn)
    568     def _apply(self, fn):
    569         for module in self.children():
--> 570             module._apply(fn)
    571 
    572         def compute_should_use_set_data(tensor, tensor_applied):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _apply(self, fn)
    591             # `with torch.no_grad():`
    592             with torch.no_grad():
--> 593                 param_applied = fn(param)
    594             should_use_set_data = compute_should_use_set_data(param, param_applied)
    595             if should_use_set_data:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in convert(t)
    895                 return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None,
    896                             non_blocking, memory_format=convert_to_format)
--> 897             return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)
    898 
    899         return self._apply(convert)

RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

Restarting the machine returned this:

```
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]
Missing logger folder: lightning_logs/nara-comments

  | Name       | Type      | Params
-----------------------------------------
0 | bert       | BertModel | 108 M 
1 | classifier | Linear    | 288 K 
2 | criterion  | BCELoss   | 0     
-----------------------------------------
108 M     Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
108 M     Total params
434.395   Total estimated model params size (MB)
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/data.py:60: UserWarning: Trying to infer the `batch_size` from an ambiguous collection. The batch size we found is 4540. To avoid any miscalculations, use `self.log(..., batch_size=batch_size)`.
  "Trying to infer the `batch_size` from an ambiguous collection. The batch size we"
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/data.py:60: UserWarning: Trying to infer the `batch_size` from an ambiguous collection. The batch size we found is 4374. To avoid any miscalculations, use `self.log(..., batch_size=batch_size)`.
  "Trying to infer the `batch_size` from an ambiguous collection. The batch size we"
Global seed set to 42
Epoch 0: 0%
0/397 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/closure.py:36: LightningDeprecationWarning: One of the returned values {'predictions', 'labels'} has a `grad_fn`. We will detach it automatically but this behaviour will change in v1.6. Please detach it manually: `return {'loss': ..., 'something': something.detach()}`
  f"One of the returned values {set(extra.keys())} has a `grad_fn`. We will detach it automatically"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-7b6b8391c42e> in <module>
----> 1 trainer.fit(model, data_module)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in fit(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, train_dataloader, ckpt_path)
    739             train_dataloaders = train_dataloader
    740         self._call_and_handle_interrupt(
--> 741             self._fit_impl, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path
    742         )
    743 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _call_and_handle_interrupt(self, trainer_fn, *args, **kwargs)
    683         """
    684         try:
--> 685             return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    686         # TODO: treat KeyboardInterrupt as BaseException (delete the code below) in v1.7
    687         except KeyboardInterrupt as exception:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _fit_impl(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path)
    775         # TODO: ckpt_path only in v1.7
    776         ckpt_path = ckpt_path or self.resume_from_checkpoint
--> 777         self._run(model, ckpt_path=ckpt_path)
    778 
    779         assert self.state.stopped

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _run(self, model, ckpt_path)
   1197 
   1198         # dispatch `start_training` or `start_evaluating` or `start_predicting`
-> 1199         self._dispatch()
   1200 
   1201         # plugin will finalized fitting (e.g. ddp_spawn will load trained model)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _dispatch(self)
   1277             self.training_type_plugin.start_predicting(self)
   1278         else:
-> 1279             self.training_type_plugin.start_training(self)
   1280 
   1281     def run_stage(self):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/training_type/training_type_plugin.py in start_training(self, trainer)
    200     def start_training(self, trainer: "pl.Trainer") -> None:
    201         # double dispatch to initiate the training loop
--> 202         self._results = trainer.run_stage()
    203 
    204     def start_evaluating(self, trainer: "pl.Trainer") -> None:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in run_stage(self)
   1287         if self.predicting:
   1288             return self._run_predict()
-> 1289         return self._run_train()
   1290 
   1291     def _pre_training_routine(self):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _run_train(self)
   1317         self.fit_loop.trainer = self
   1318         with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(self._detect_anomaly):
-> 1319             self.fit_loop.run()
   1320 
   1321     def _run_evaluate(self) -> _EVALUATE_OUTPUT:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/base.py in run(self, *args, **kwargs)
    143             try:
    144                 self.on_advance_start(*args, **kwargs)
--> 145                 self.advance(*args, **kwargs)
    146                 self.on_advance_end()
    147                 self.restarting = False

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/fit_loop.py in advance(self)
    232 
    233         with self.trainer.profiler.profile("run_training_epoch"):
--> 234             self.epoch_loop.run(data_fetcher)
    235 
    236             # the global step is manually decreased here due to backwards compatibility with existing loggers

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/base.py in run(self, *args, **kwargs)
    143             try:
    144                 self.on_advance_start(*args, **kwargs)
--> 145                 self.advance(*args, **kwargs)
    146                 self.on_advance_end()
    147                 self.restarting = False

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/epoch/training_epoch_loop.py in advance(self, *args, **kwargs)
    191 
    192             with self.trainer.profiler.profile("run_training_batch"):
--> 193                 batch_output = self.batch_loop.run(batch, batch_idx)
    194 
    195         self.batch_progress.increment_processed()

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/base.py in run(self, *args, **kwargs)
    143             try:
    144                 self.on_advance_start(*args, **kwargs)
--> 145                 self.advance(*args, **kwargs)
    146                 self.on_advance_end()
    147                 self.restarting = False

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/batch/training_batch_loop.py in advance(self, batch, batch_idx)
     86         if self.trainer.lightning_module.automatic_optimization:
     87             optimizers = _get_active_optimizers(self.trainer.optimizers, self.trainer.optimizer_frequencies, batch_idx)
---> 88             outputs = self.optimizer_loop.run(split_batch, optimizers, batch_idx)
     89         else:
     90             outputs = self.manual_loop.run(split_batch, batch_idx)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/base.py in run(self, *args, **kwargs)
    143             try:
    144                 self.on_advance_start(*args, **kwargs)
--> 145                 self.advance(*args, **kwargs)
    146                 self.on_advance_end()
    147                 self.restarting = False

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/optimizer_loop.py in advance(self, batch, *args, **kwargs)
    217             self._batch_idx,
    218             self._optimizers[self.optim_progress.optimizer_position],
--> 219             self.optimizer_idx,
    220         )
    221         if result.loss is not None:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/optimizer_loop.py in _run_optimization(self, split_batch, batch_idx, optimizer, opt_idx)
    264         # gradient update with accumulated gradients
    265         else:
--> 266             self._optimizer_step(optimizer, opt_idx, batch_idx, closure)
    267 
    268         result = closure.consume_result()

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/optimizer_loop.py in _optimizer_step(self, optimizer, opt_idx, batch_idx, train_step_and_backward_closure)
    384             on_tpu=(self.trainer._device_type == DeviceType.TPU and _TPU_AVAILABLE),
    385             using_native_amp=(self.trainer.amp_backend is not None and self.trainer.amp_backend == AMPType.NATIVE),
--> 386             using_lbfgs=is_lbfgs,
    387         )
    388 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/lightning.py in optimizer_step(self, epoch, batch_idx, optimizer, optimizer_idx, optimizer_closure, on_tpu, using_native_amp, using_lbfgs)
   1650 
   1651         """
-> 1652         optimizer.step(closure=optimizer_closure)
   1653 
   1654     def optimizer_zero_grad(self, epoch: int, batch_idx: int, optimizer: Optimizer, optimizer_idx: int):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/optimizer.py in step(self, closure, **kwargs)
    162         assert trainer is not None
    163         with trainer.profiler.profile(profiler_action):
--> 164             trainer.accelerator.optimizer_step(self._optimizer, self._optimizer_idx, closure, **kwargs)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py in optimizer_step(self, optimizer, opt_idx, closure, model, **kwargs)
    337         """
    338         model = model or self.lightning_module
--> 339         self.precision_plugin.optimizer_step(model, optimizer, opt_idx, closure, **kwargs)
    340 
    341     def optimizer_zero_grad(self, current_epoch: int, batch_idx: int, optimizer: Optimizer, opt_idx: int) -> None:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/precision/precision_plugin.py in optimizer_step(self, model, optimizer, optimizer_idx, closure, **kwargs)
    161         if isinstance(model, pl.LightningModule):
    162             closure = partial(self._wrap_closure, model, optimizer, optimizer_idx, closure)
--> 163         optimizer.step(closure=closure, **kwargs)
    164 
    165     def _track_grad_norm(self, trainer: "pl.Trainer") -> None:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     63                 instance._step_count += 1
     64                 wrapped = func.__get__(instance, cls)
---> 65                 return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     66 
     67             # Note that the returned function here is no longer a bound method,

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     86                 profile_name = "Optimizer.step#{}.step".format(obj.__class__.__name__)
     87                 with torch.autograd.profiler.record_function(profile_name):
---> 88                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
     89             return wrapper
     90 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/optimization.py in step(self, closure)
    330         loss = None
    331         if closure is not None:
--> 332             loss = closure()
    333 
    334         for group in self.param_groups:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/precision/precision_plugin.py in _wrap_closure(self, model, optimizer, optimizer_idx, closure)
    146         consistent with the ``PrecisionPlugin`` subclasses that cannot pass ``optimizer.step(closure)`` directly.
    147         """
--> 148         closure_result = closure()
    149         self._after_closure(model, optimizer, optimizer_idx)
    150         return closure_result

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/optimizer_loop.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    158 
    159     def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Optional[Tensor]:
--> 160         self._result = self.closure(*args, **kwargs)
    161         return self._result.loss
    162 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/optimizer_loop.py in closure(self, *args, **kwargs)
    153             if self._backward_fn is not None and step_output.closure_loss is not None:
    154                 with self._profiler.profile("backward"):
--> 155                     self._backward_fn(step_output.closure_loss)
    156 
    157         return step_output

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/optimizer_loop.py in backward_fn(loss)
    325 
    326         def backward_fn(loss: Tensor) -> None:
--> 327             self.trainer.accelerator.backward(loss, optimizer, opt_idx)
    328 
    329             # check if model weights are nan

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py in backward(self, closure_loss, *args, **kwargs)
    312         closure_loss = self.precision_plugin.pre_backward(self.lightning_module, closure_loss)
    313 
--> 314         self.precision_plugin.backward(self.lightning_module, closure_loss, *args, **kwargs)
    315 
    316         closure_loss = self.precision_plugin.post_backward(self.lightning_module, closure_loss)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/precision/precision_plugin.py in backward(self, model, closure_loss, optimizer, *args, **kwargs)
     89         # do backward pass
     90         if model is not None and isinstance(model, pl.LightningModule):
---> 91             model.backward(closure_loss, optimizer, *args, **kwargs)
     92         else:
     93             self._run_backward(closure_loss, *args, **kwargs)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/lightning.py in backward(self, loss, optimizer, optimizer_idx, *args, **kwargs)
   1432                 loss.backward()
   1433         """
-> 1434         loss.backward(*args, **kwargs)
   1435 
   1436     def toggle_optimizer(self, optimizer: Union[Optimizer, LightningOptimizer], optimizer_idx: int) -> None:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs)
    305                 create_graph=create_graph,
    306                 inputs=inputs)
--> 307         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
    308 
    309     def register_hook(self, hook):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    154     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
    155         tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
--> 156         allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
    157 
    158 

RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

Comment: Just thinking out loud, but maybe BERT needs a CUDA capable GPU?

Comment: Could you provide your GPU information from `nvidia-smi`?

Comment: Also, this problem might not be relevant to BERT or PL libraries. Can you assign a tensor to GPU? For example, `a = torch.tensor([0]).to("cuda")`.

Comment: Here is my GPU information. 

| NVIDIA-SMI 510.47.03    Driver Version: 510.47.03    CUDA Version: 11.6     |

| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
                                                                       MIG M. |

|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   43C    P0    41W / 300W |  12809MiB / 16384MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                                      N/A |

Comment: Yes @joe32140, `print(a)` returns `tensor([0], device='cuda:0')`

Comment: Have you tried to restart the machine?

Comment: Also, can you try to run it on CPU to rule out CUDA issues?

Comment: I have edited my orginal post, that's the updated error I recieved on restarting.

Comment: It can be index out of range error. Can you try on CPU?